# what is the api for redirecting i/o of serial device to standard i/o in linux

Tags: c, linux, vxworks

I am trying to port Vxworks application to Linux. For redirecting i/o of one of the serial device to standard i/o they are using ioTaskStdSet(); in vxworks.
But I am not able to find the api in linux like as. Only duplicating device is available in linux that is also not working in my application.

Can anyone help me out in this?

Comment: Other than `dup2()`?

Comment: We need a [mcve]. It is quite unclear what you're trying here.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Ignacio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams) mentioned dup2 is used exactly for this purpose. For example this program redirect stdout to "echo" file:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int fd = open("echo", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 00644);
    if(fd == -1)
        return 1;

    if(dup2(fd, 1) == -1)
        return 1;
    close(fd);

    system("echo Hi!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I want to use old file descriptor can i ignore close(fd)? And I am using this duplicating in multiple threads but it is working in only one thread. In second thread again stdi/o redirecting to second terminal. What should i do for redirecting stdi/o to several terminals using multiple threads?

Comment: @jyothi: If you use old file descriptor (let's say you call `write(fd, ...)`) then why do you need to duplicate something? So no, after `dup2` you normally call `close`. About threads and terminals, I'm not sure to understand. I think your question can be really interesting, but we need some examples, it's would be great if you edit your post. For example when you say: "I am using this duplicating in multiple threads but it is working in only one thread" it's difficult to help you without seeing your code.

Comment: I am currently working on telnet client application using 4 terminal ports. That is why For my application requirement I want to use both.

Comment: int ts_fd;
int main()
{
 for(i=0;i<4;i++)
 {
       sprintf(dev_name,"tsports%d",i);
       fd[i] = open(dev,O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
       pthread_create(tid[i],NULL,&thread_fun,(void *)fd[i]);
 }
 pthread_exit(NULL);
}
int thread_fun(void *chan)
{
     int new_fd,old_fd;
     old_fd = (int)chan;
    
     new_fd = dup2(old_fd,0);
     new_fd = dup2(old_fd,1);
     ts_fd = old_fd;
     tn();
     pthread_exit(NULL);
}

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        sprintf(dev_name,"tsports%d",i);
        fd[i] = open(dev,O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
        pthread_create(tid[i],NULL,&thread_fun,(void *)fd[i]);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
int thread_fun(void *chan)
{
     int new_fd,old_fd;
     old_fd = (int)chan;

     new_fd = dup2(old_fd,0);
     new_fd = dup2(old_fd,1);
     ts_fd = old_fd;
     tn();
     pthread_exit(NULL);
}
void tn()
{
     printf("hello on terminal");
     while(1)
     {
          read(ts_fd,&ch,1);
          /* command line */
          ........
          ........
          ........

          /* starts telnet client application on terminal port*/         
          .......
       ......
           ......
          .......
          sleep(1);
     }
}

 In the above code while taking input from terminal 1 it is again redirecting stdi/o to terminal 2 in second thread.
```

So i want thread specific stdi/o even though redirected on each terminal. That is available in Vxworks as IoTaskStdSet API.
 Is it possible to implement in linux.